# Is anything outside the solarsystem where Kerbin resides?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

So, I wanted to recreate the Voyager and see how far into space I could launch a probe.

As it stands now I've gotten past the highest orbit of the outermost planet (Eelo) and when I quit the game just now the probe was about 150 billion meters (atleast I think it was meters) from the sun.

Can I get out of the solarsystem? Is there anything outside it? I can't scroll out anymore now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can leave the Kerbin solar system in the sense you can go forward to infinity, but there isn't anything else past Eelo. The only celestial bodies in Kerbin Space Program right now are the ones in the wiki.

[Celestials](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Celestials)

<s>There are discussions regarding adding other solar systems</s>
The forum lost everything since october 2012, so, i refer to this from the wiki.

> The Kerbol System is at the moment the only available solar system.

[Kerbol System](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Kerbol_System)